# How do I get Selenium to find this error indicator

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am writing an automation script for

http://computer-database.gatling.io/computers/new

When an invalid value (or no computer name) is entered and save is clicked an error indicator appears (the field turns red)

However I can't get Selenium to find the error indicator

I have not worked with this type of error before so not sure what to look for 
my code

Locator

```
computer_name_required = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main > form > fieldset > div:nth-child(1) > div")

    invalid_intro_date = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main > form > fieldset > div:nth-child(2) > div")

    invalid_dscon_date = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#main > form > fieldset > div:nth-child(3) > div)")
```

using element is displayed

```
def element_displayed(self, *element):
        element = self.browser.find_element(*element)

        if element.is_displayed():
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The invalid name method

```
def invalid_name_error(self):
    return self.element_displayed(*CreateAndEditPageLocators.computer_name_required)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the class name changes when an error occurs you could use the xPath instead of css selector

```
".//*[@class='clearfix error']//*[@for='name']"         #for computer name error
".//*[@class='clearfix error']//*[@for='introduced']"   #for introduced error
".//*[@class='clearfix error']//*[@for='discontinued']" #for discontinued error
```